# Is Window.innerHeight the just the scroll bar height?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, domdocument

I wrote a simple JavaScript program and found that the `window.innerHeight` is equal to the scroll bar height. Is `window.innerHeight` just equal to the scroll bar height? If that's the case, how does one get the actual window height?

Comment: That is the actual height of the window, i.e. the viewport: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight . If you want to get the height of the content, you can use [`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) of `body` or `html` element.

Comment: You can find the answer here:
[Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window)